# Appending a list in this situation

Tags: python, list, append

This is the question,
Write a Python program to find numbers in between 100 and 400 (both inclusive) where each digit of
the numbers is an even number. The numbers obtained should be printed in a comma-separated
sequence. I'm only allowed to use while loops so I'm not sure how.
Edited: It has to in a single line

My current code:

```py
x = 100
while x < 400:
    x += 2
    str_x = str(x)
    if int (str_x[0]) % 2 == 0 and int(str_x[1]) % 2 == 0 and int(str_x[2]) % 2 == 0:
        l = [str_x]
        print(l)
```

Comment: First of all, please don't attach screenshots, rather you can put some code in backquotes.
Second of all, as you have already restriction to use `while` loop, can you use some extra python packages? @Ham

Comment: You already have the soltion, what else do you want?

Comment: Another approach using list-comp and set-intersection (not `while`, thus not an answer). `[i for i in range(100, 401) if not set(str(i)) & set("13579")]` Note that no number in the 100s or 300s can match the criterion, though, so you might as well restrict the search to 200-299 and add 400 separately.

Comment: Thanks @mckraqs for all the advice.  I'm new to StackOverflow and coding.

Comment: @MohitC, it has to be in a single line whereas mine has multiple rows.

Comment: @tobias_k, that is true too thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just some correction to have a list with all the values at the end. With only using a `while` loop.

```py
x = 100
l = []
while x < 400:
    x += 2
    str_x = str(x)
    if int(str_x[0]) % 2 == 0 and int(str_x[1]) % 2 == 0 and int(str_x[2]) % 2 == 0:
        l.append(x)
print(l)
```

A more pythonic way in doing this:

```py
l = lambda a, b : [
    x for x in range(a, b+1) 
    if all(int(digit) % 2 == 0 for digit in str(x)) 
]
print(l(200, 401))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the values in a `list`, and at the end print them comma-separated

```
x = 100
keep = []
while x <= 400:
    strx = str(x)
    if all(int(digit) % 2 == 0 for digit in strx):
        keep.append(strx)
    x += 2
print(",".join(keep))
# 200,202,204,206,208,220,222,224,226,228,240,242,244,246,248,260,262,264,266,268,280,282,284,286,288,400
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with only while loops and without converting to string:

```
i = 100
while i <= 400:
    d = i
    flag = True
    while d > 0:
        d,r = divmod(d,10)
        if r%2:
            flag = False
    if flag:
        print(i)
    i += 2 # optimization as only even numbers are valid
```

output (as single line):

```
200 202 204 206 208 220 222 224 226 228 240 242 244 246 248 260 262 264 266 268 280 282 284 286 288 400
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant you just do :

```
x= 100 # start number
while x <= 400:
  odds = ['1','3','5','7','9'] # odds
  t = len(str(x)) # how long string is
  v = 0 # a variable
  for i in list(str(x)): # a for loop
    if i not in odds:# checking if its even or not
      v += 1 # adds 1 to v
    else:
      v += 0
  if v == t: #if its all even,
    print(x, end = ',') #print it out.
  x += 1 # move on to next one
#200,202,204,206,208,220,222,224,226,228,240,242,244,246,248,260,262,264,266,268,280,282,284,286,288,400,
```

Comment: This returns : 200,202,204,206,208,220,222,224,226,228,240,242,244,246,248,260,262,264,266,268,280,282,284,286,288,400,